# Weird order after select() (with FD_SET())

Tags: c, select, unix-socket

I am developing a multi-client Unix Domain Socket to transfer data through multiple processes. I found some code that implements chat between every client and stuff but I want that once a client send something to the server, the server reply back and the client disconnect.

Having that said, I don't want `while(fgets())` but I want (on client side):

```
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    fd_set readfds;
    char buf[1024];
    char buf2[1024];
    int len;

    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&remote, len) == -1)
        /* handle error */

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(0, &readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);

    if(select(sockfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
        /* handle error */

    if(FD_ISSET(0, &readfds)) {
        fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
        if(write(sockfd, buf, 1024) <= 0)
            /* handle error */
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &readfds)) {
        if(read(sockfd, &buf2, 1024) <= 0)
            /* handle error */
    }

    printf("%s\n", buf2);

    close(sockfd);
}
```

In this order, it works if I do everything after `connect()` twice (with a loop) but I want to do it only once. Without this loop, my server (which is a daemon) crash and I don't know why.

Furthermore, I added `printf()` from the code above to understand how it works:

```
(...)
printf("before select\n");
fflush(stdout);

if(select(sockfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    /* handle error */

printf("before select\n");
fflush(stdout);

if(FD_ISSET(0, &readfds)) {
    fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
    if(write(sockfd, buf, 1024) <= 0)
        /* handle error */
}
(...)
```

And I have this output:

```
before select
"input to fgets"
after select
```

And I don't understand why I have the input BEFORE "after select". It doesn't make any sense to me since I call `fgets()` after `printf()`.

I hope this is understandable enough.
What's wrong with my code ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: you're missing declarations of all your variables, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: and a lot of your function calls seem to be missing parameters ie `write(sockfd, str)` should have 3 parameters

Comment: `printf` is line buffered when connected to a terminal. Either add `\n` to your printfs or `fflush(stdout);` after each.

Comment: I added everything you need, I wanted to write the less possible code. 
I just tried to add `fflush(stdout)` and it doesn't change anything

Comment: `if(read(sockfd, &buf2, 1024) <= 0)
            /* handle error */` read returning -1 is not always *an error*. check errno, and decide what to do next for instance on EAGAIN / EWOULDBLOCK

Comment: I'll check that, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time through, you call `select()` before the server has responded. The result is that `sockfd` won't be ready for reading.

In your case, the client might not need `select()` on the `sockfd`. You know that if you wrote something to the server you want to wait for the reply, right?

Comment: What is the point of `select()` then ? I just tried and it works perfectly without calling `select()`. But it has been called before `read()` or `write()` in every socket example I've seen

Comment: `select()` or the newer `poll()`  are used to monitor several sockets/file descriptors at once. The typical case is a single-threaded server with multiple client connections.

Comment: So it is only useful on the server side ? Or if a client connects to multiple servers ?

Comment: Yes. You can also use it to implement a timeout on a read. If you call `select()` with the timeout parameter set, you can wait a predetermined time for a response.